# Multiplication in matlab

Tags: matlab, multiplication

4.082*2118
When I write this multiplication in MATLAB software, I get this answer: 1.705868e+04
but I want to show the answer like this: 17058.68
what is my wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Matlab console, type `format rational`. Example:

```
>> 4.082 * 2118

ans =

   8.6457e+03

>> format rational
>> 4.082 * 2118

ans =

  319890/37
```

You can also use the [rat](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rat.html) and [rats](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rats.html) functions. The rat function can also give you the numerator and the denominator as numbers:

```
>> [num, denom] = rat(4.082 * 2118)

num =

  319890       


denom =

      37
```

Note that the result is only an approximation. You can improve it by decreasing the tolerance:

```
>> [num, denom] = rat(4.082 * 2118, 0)

num =

 2161419       


denom =

     250
```